# CustomRepository clashes with <S>save(S) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository return type java.lang.Long is not compatible with S

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save a record in DB, which in return should return me the primary key.

here is my Entity Class:

```
@Entity
public class CustomEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;
private Integer eventTypeId;
//getter setter here
}
```

Here goes my repository:

```
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomEntity, Long> {
Long save(customRepository);
}
```

When i try to call the repository interface in my Service class, I get this Exception at compile time:

```
Error:(32, 8) java: save(model.CustomEntity) in repository.CustomRepository clashes with <S>save(S) 
in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository return type java.lang.Long is not compatible with S
```

I understand JPA Repository extends PaginationAndSorting which in returns extends CrudRepository, how do i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the methods signature is

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity)
```

so you need to return the same Type as you pass as parameter. In your case `CustomEntity`.

Comment: I understand that, but can I not get primary key directly as return when I save?

Comment: No, but even better, you get the whole object back withe the primary key set :-)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter's type and return value should be the same.
try to change your code:

```
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomEntity, Long> {
CustomEntity save(customRepository);
}
```

and then get id value from `CustomEntity` object for example:

```
public void someMethod(){
  CustomEntity entity = repo.save(new CustomEntity());
  Long savedId = entity.getId();
}
```